# Problem with STOCKHISTORY() and Dynamic Arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let me explain my problem with the STOCKHISTORY() function.

[image]

1. It retrieves the closing prices for a single stock ticker as expected, no problem so far (first "table").
2. However, I want to use STOCKHISTORY for all the tickers that appear in a table that may grow with time. In this case, STOCKHISTORY fails to retrieve all history prices except for the first line (second "table").
3. What I am looking for is a single dynamic array formula with STOCKHISTORY that shows the complete price history for all the tickers that will be placed in an excel table (varying length) (third "table").

It seems to me that this a bug of the STOCKHISTORY function, but I may be wrong. Or perhaps, there is a workaround that may solve my problem.

Any suggestions?

Remark: I have added a picture of my excel sheet. Because I use the international settings for Spain, dates are shown in dd/mm/yyyy format and constant horizontal arrays use the "" separator (in the US the separator is the ",").

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be resolved by creating arrays out of the Start_date and End_date inputs.

Here an example screenshot:

[image]

for the Start_dates array I used this formula:

```
=EDATE($C$2,SEQUENCE(MONTH($C$3)-MONTH($C$2)+1,1,0,1))
```

and for the End_dates array this formula:

```
=EDATE($C$2,SEQUENCE(MONTH($C$3)-MONTH($C$2)+1,1,1,1))
```

which only differs by a 1 instead of 0 in the penultimate SEQUENCE() index

> Edit 1

The formulas for the dates arrays only work for monthly differences within the same year. But I'll leave that small adjustment to you. Just an example here.

Comment: in fact, after checking your answer, I have realized that the end_date is not really necessary and can be omitted altogether.

Comment: ... which it still better for me !!!